# Can I assign the value like this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do something like this is this possible?

```
<%
var Controller = null;
if (Model.ID== "ABC")
    {
        Controller = "Name";
    }
    else
    {
        Controller = "Detail";
    }
%>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("edit", Controller, FormMethod.Post, new { @id="exc-" + Model.SID}))
   {%>
<%= Html.Summary(true)%>
```

Is this possible?

If i do I am getting exception:

> ERROR: Cannot assign  to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: Did someones edit wipe out the question?

Comment: Why would you delete most of your question and leave the part that is of the least amount of help?  Rollback?

Comment: @Dan Blair yes the OP did... I just did a rollback and fixed up the grammer / formatting.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in such a way that it completely destroys the meaning of the question or its answers.

Comment: Rolled back to a revision that actually has content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
<% var Controller = (Model.ID == "ABC") ? "Name" : "Details" %>
```

**EDIT:** Based in your update do:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("edit", 
    (Model.ID == "ABC") ? "Name" : "Details", FormMethod.Post,
    new { @id="exc-" + Model.SID})) 
   { %>
```

You could also use your code that you editted and just change `var` to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
var Controller = null;

if (Model.ID == "ABC")
    {
        Controller = "Name";
    }
    else
    {
        Controller = "Details";
    }
%>
```

Comment: This won't produce the desired result.  In the question, the `Controller` variable is a JavaScript one, with the ASP.NET code running in inline code blocks around it.

Comment: the `Controller` is not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Either way, this is wrong.  If it's supposed to be a JavaScript variable, it shouldn't be in a `<%` / `%>` block, and if it's supposed to be a C# variable, then the statement `var Controller = null` is illegal, because the expression `null` actually has no type.

Comment: In the original OP he was trying to do it in JS.  However, the correct solution should not use JS.  But Daniel is also correct - in C#, the compiler must be able to determine the type of a "var" at compile time based on whatever is on the right-hand side of the statement.